# Using Spark and MongoDb to find the Largest and Smallest Cities by State

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I am very new to Spart and Mongo DB. I am trying to learn it.

```
{ "_id" : "01040", "city" : "HOLYOKE", "loc" : [ -72.626193, 42.202007 ], "pop_size" : 43704, "state" : "MA" }
{ "_id" : "01050", "city" : "HUNTINGTON", "loc" : [ -72.873341, 42.265301 ], "pop_size" : 2084, "state" : "MA" }    
{ "_id" : "01033", "city" : "GRANBY", "loc" : [ -72.52000099999999, 42.255704 ], "pop_size" : 5526, "state" : "MA" }
{ "_id" : "01034", "city" : "TOLLAND", "loc" : [ -72.908793, 42.070234 ], "pop_size" : 1652, "state" : "CA" }
```

For a json like above, I want find Largest and Smallest Cities by State.

```
zips_df.groupby('state', 'city').sum('pop').withColumnRenamed("sum(pop)", "total population").sort().
```

I grouped data and sort it. Then, I am not sure the next.... Can I get some help?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use analytic function
Please refer below link to get the idea
[Difference in dense rank and row number in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968912/difference-in-dense-rank-and-row-number-in-spark)

Answer (score 0):

You should just use take(1) to get the first row. Because you need to sort the dataframe twice (one in ascending mode and one in descending), you should cache it first in order for groupBy, sum and withColumnRenamed not to be calculated twice. Notice that take(1) returns a list of one item, so we have to take the item in index 0.

```
grouped_df = zips_df \
      .groupBy('state', 'city') \
      .sum('pop_size') \
      .withColumnRenamed('sum(pop_size)', 'total population') \
      .cache()

smallest = grouped_df.sort(col("total population")).take(1)[0]
largest = grouped_df.sort(col("total population").desc()).take(1)[0]
```

Now you can get the city name like that:

```
smallest.city
```