# Pyspark: how to associate to each string IDs an integer number?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like the following

```
+------------------------------------+-------------------+--------+------------------+-----------+
|ID                                  |timestamp          |accuracy|lat               |lon        |
+------------------------------------+-------------------+--------+------------------+-----------+
|5ab75a28-ed7f-4819-b781-640f8784ca6b|2020-01-01 04:54:04|13.2    |32.768036         |-97.0996884|
|eef755ef-de7b-4de1-931d-42d204990a07|2020-01-01 09:13:33|16.0    |21.377116         |-157.92295 |
|eef755ef-de7b-4de1-931d-42d204990a07|2020-01-01 09:13:33|16.0    |21.377116         |-157.92295 |
|eef755ef-de7b-4de1-931d-42d204990a07|2020-01-01 09:13:33|16.0    |21.377116         |-157.92295 |
|6408d32b-5e64-43cb-9022-79a1baf8f1a0|2020-01-01 14:00:11|14.1    |25.8491957        |-80.1753329|
|52ad3006-a105-4501-b9f8-9658edc6380a|2020-01-01 21:03:25|12.97   |33.016752499999996|-96.8533025|
|3676d46f-429c-4706-b43a-b1370391c1d0|2020-01-01 22:29:22|8.0     |29.536905         |-95.265337 |
|3676d46f-429c-4706-b43a-b1370391c1d0|2020-01-01 22:29:22|8.0     |29.536905         |-95.265337 |
+------------------------------------+-------------------+--------+------------------+-----------+
```

I would like to associate to each `ID` an integer number and have a column `code` like the following

```
df['code']
0
1
1
1
2
3
4
4
```

If I do

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import dense_rank
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df.withColumn("code", dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy("timestamp"))).show()
```

I get

```
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+----+
|                  ID|          timestamp|          accuracy|               lat|                lon|code|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+----+
|59ae42df-37f3-4d5...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               2.0| 39.53418731689453|-105.03048706054688|   1|
|2fd86c2c-eb94-42f...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               6.0|  40.4071159362793| -92.56725311279297|   1|
|3739eb5b-ee20-440...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               4.0|  44.7714958190918|  -85.0419692993164|   1|
|6daab4ca-52c5-436...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|15.100000381469727|32.661895751953125|-115.45074462890625|   1|
|0162e422-5b2b-49b...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              16.0|34.127418518066406| -84.67899322509766|   1|
|92d321cf-e907-4c6...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              10.0|37.662391662597656| -76.42019653320312|   1|
|3c1835a9-35a5-49d...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|12.300000190734863|32.696022033691406| -97.17048645019531|   1|
|1ab5a5bf-4511-44c...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              17.0|40.704708099365234| -73.91097259521484|   1|
|4a8b1299-1485-443...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|12.399999618530273|             39.25| -78.08999633789062|   1|
|7ba6c144-b7c2-4bf...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              17.0|30.124404907226562| -95.55699920654297|   1|
|3290f184-7b56-414...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              10.0| 36.62535095214844| -119.3048095703125|   1|
|f677d8e3-2fc6-47a...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               5.0|  27.9086856842041| -82.51069641113281|   1|
|bcab074a-c5dd-406...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               5.0|  34.4466667175293|  -82.4963150024414|   1|
|1bb2532d-eb3c-47b...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               5.0|27.372886657714844| -80.41101837158203|   1|
|8c6692c1-cb82-441...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               8.0|29.719207763671875| -95.76821899414062|   1|
|d427fae2-26f7-47f...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               5.0|31.151153564453125| -82.45683288574219|   1|
|db5c0e25-55df-44c...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|12.300000190734863| 40.85110092163086| -73.88435363769531|   1|
|2f61f080-65aa-4e5...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              12.0|  36.2707405090332| -80.37544250488281|   1|
|ab9c61bb-7760-472...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              15.0| 45.99789810180664|-112.59880065917969|   1|
|4b6a8d0f-ffd4-492...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               5.0| 35.16313934326172| -80.95419311523438|   1|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`dense_rank`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import dense_rank
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df.withColumn("code", dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy("ID"))) \
    .show()
```

*output*

```
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+----+
|                  ID|          timestamp|          accuracy|               lat|                lon|code|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+----+
|0162e422-5b2b-49b...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              16.0| 34.12741851806641| -84.67899322509766|   1|
|1ab5a5bf-4511-44c...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              17.0| 40.70470809936523| -73.91097259521484|   2|
|1bb2532d-eb3c-47b...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               5.0|27.372886657714844| -80.41101837158203|   3|
|2f61f080-65aa-4e5...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              12.0|  36.2707405090332| -80.37544250488281|   4|
|2fd86c2c-eb94-42f...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               6.0|  40.4071159362793| -92.56725311279295|   5|
|3290f184-7b56-414...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              10.0| 36.62535095214844| -119.3048095703125|   6|
|3739eb5b-ee20-440...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               4.0|  44.7714958190918|  -85.0419692993164|   7|
|3c1835a9-35a5-49d...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|12.300000190734865| 32.69602203369141| -97.17048645019531|   8|
|4a8b1299-1485-443...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|12.399999618530273|             39.25| -78.08999633789062|   9|
|4b6a8d0f-ffd4-492...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               5.0| 35.16313934326172| -80.95419311523438|  10|
|59ae42df-37f3-4d5...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               2.0| 39.53418731689453|-105.03048706054688|  11|
|6daab4ca-52c5-436...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|15.100000381469727|32.661895751953125|-115.45074462890624|  12|
|7ba6c144-b7c2-4bf...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              17.0| 30.12440490722656| -95.55699920654295|  13|
|8c6692c1-cb82-441...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               8.0|29.719207763671875| -95.76821899414062|  14|
|92d321cf-e907-4c6...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              10.0|37.662391662597656| -76.42019653320312|  15|
|ab9c61bb-7760-472...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|              15.0| 45.99789810180664|-112.59880065917969|  16|
|bcab074a-c5dd-406...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               5.0|34.446666717529304|  -82.4963150024414|  17|
|d427fae2-26f7-47f...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               5.0|31.151153564453125| -82.45683288574219|  18|
|db5c0e25-55df-44c...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|12.300000190734865| 40.85110092163086| -73.88435363769531|  19|
|f677d8e3-2fc6-47a...|2020-01-01 00:00:00|               5.0|  27.9086856842041| -82.51069641113281|  20|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+----+
```

You can subtract `-1` if you want to start at 0.

Comment: The problem is that I have different IDs at the same timestamp. I show you the output on the question.

Comment: Is it the order of `code` a problem ? A solution is to replace `Window.orderBy("timestamp")` with `Window.orderBy("ID")`, but doing so, the dataset will be reordered.. Let me know

Comment: No, it is not a problem I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try with row_number function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.withColumn("row_number", f.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("timestamp")))
```

Comment: row_number() will start again with 1 if it encounters new value for timestamp ... so you will have to use dense_rank in place of row_number

Comment: It depends on the case, in this case it probably fits better row_number, you can check it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44969230/7306659

Comment: He doesn't want to skip the sequence  in columns .. so in this case, dense_rank is well suited

Comment: the problem is that I have different IDs at the same timestamp. Please see the revised question

Comment: for this reason I said to use row_number, please check it out