# Multiple files ranking using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have stock data (over 6000+ stocks, 100+ GB) saved as HDF5 file.

Basically, I am trying to translate this pandas code into pyspark. Ideally, I would love to have values used for the ranking, as well as ranks themselves saved to a file.

```
agg_df = pd.DataFrame()
for stock in stocks:
    df = pd.read_csv(stock)
    df = my_func(df) # custom function, output of which will be used for ranking. For simplicity, can use standard deviation
    agg_df = pd.concat([agg_df, df], ax=1) # row-wise concat

agg_df.rank() #.to_csv() <- would like to save ranks for future use
```

Each data file has the same schema like:

```
                   Symbol   Open   High    Low  Close   Volume
DateTime
2010-09-13 09:30:00      A  29.23  29.25  29.17  29.25  17667.0
2010-09-13 09:31:00      A  29.26  29.34  29.25  29.33   5000.0
2010-09-13 09:32:00      A  29.31  29.36  29.31  29.36    600.0
2010-09-13 09:33:00      A  29.33  29.36  29.30  29.35   7300.0
2010-09-13 09:34:00      A  29.35  29.39  29.31  29.39   3222.0
```

Desired output (where each number is a rank):

```
                      A   AAPL MSFT ...etc
DateTime
2010-09-13 09:30:00   1   3    7    ...
2010-09-13 09:31:00   4   5    7    ...
2010-09-13 09:32:00   24  17   99   ...
2010-09-13 09:33:00   7   63   42   ...
2010-09-13 09:34:00   5   4    13   ...
```

I read other answers about Window and pyspark.sql, but not sure how to apply those to my case as I kind of need to aggregate those by row before ranking (at least in pandas)

Edit 1: After I read the data to an rdd `rdd = sc.parallelize(data.keys).map(data.read_data)`, rdd becomes a PipelineRDD, which doesnt have .select() method. 0xDFDFDFDF's example contains all data in one dataframe, but I dont think it's a good idea to append everything to one dataframe to do the computation.

Result: Finally was able to solve it. There were 2 problems: reading files and performing the calculations.

Regarding reading file, I initially loaded them from HDF5 using `rdd = sc.parallelize(data.keys).map(data.read_data)` which resulted in PipelineRDD, which was a collection of pandas dataframes. These needed to be transformed to spark dataframe in order for the solution to work. I ended up transforming my hdf5 file to parquet and saved them to a separate folder. Then using

```
sqlContext = pyspark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
rdd_p = sqlContext.read.parquet(r"D:\parq")
```

read all the files to a dataframe.

After that performed calculation from accepted answer. Huge thanks to 0xDFDFDFDF for help

Extras:

discussion - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214307/discussion-between-biarys-and-0xdfdfdfdf

0xDFDFDFDF solution - https://gist.github.com/0xDFDFDFDF/a93a7e4448abc03f606008c7422784d1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, windows functions will do the trick.
I've created a small mock dataset, which should resemble yours.

```
columns = ['DateTime', 'Symbol', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

data = [('2010-09-13 09:30:00','A',29.23,29.25,29.17,29.25,17667.0), 
        ('2010-09-13 09:31:00','A',29.26,29.34,29.25,29.33,5000.0),
        ('2010-09-13 09:32:00','A',29.31,29.36,29.31,29.36,600.0),
        ('2010-09-13 09:34:00','A',29.35,29.39,29.31,29.39,3222.0),
        ('2010-09-13 09:30:00','AAPL',39.23,39.25,39.17,39.25,37667.0), 
        ('2010-09-13 09:31:00','AAPL',39.26,39.34,39.25,39.33,3000.0),
        ('2010-09-13 09:32:00','AAPL',39.31,39.36,39.31,39.36,300.0),
        ('2010-09-13 09:33:00','AAPL',39.33,39.36,39.30,39.35,3300.0),
        ('2010-09-13 09:34:00','AAPL',39.35,39.39,39.31,39.39,4222.0),
        ('2010-09-13 09:34:00','MSFT',39.35,39.39,39.31,39.39,7222.0)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

Now, `df.show()` will give us this:

```
+-------------------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|           DateTime|Symbol| Open| High|  Low|Close| Volume|
+-------------------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
|2010-09-13 09:30:00|     A|29.23|29.25|29.17|29.25|17667.0|
|2010-09-13 09:31:00|     A|29.26|29.34|29.25|29.33| 5000.0|
|2010-09-13 09:32:00|     A|29.31|29.36|29.31|29.36|  600.0|
|2010-09-13 09:34:00|     A|29.35|29.39|29.31|29.39| 3222.0|
|2010-09-13 09:30:00|  AAPL|39.23|39.25|39.17|39.25|37667.0|
|2010-09-13 09:31:00|  AAPL|39.26|39.34|39.25|39.33| 3000.0|
|2010-09-13 09:32:00|  AAPL|39.31|39.36|39.31|39.36|  300.0|
|2010-09-13 09:33:00|  AAPL|39.33|39.36| 39.3|39.35| 3300.0|
|2010-09-13 09:34:00|  AAPL|39.35|39.39|39.31|39.39| 4222.0|
|2010-09-13 09:34:00|  MSFT|39.35|39.39|39.31|39.39| 7222.0|
+-------------------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------+
```

Here's the solution, which uses the aforementioned window function for `rank()`. Some transformation is needed, for which you can use `pivot()` function.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

result = (df
 .select(
     'DateTime',
     'Symbol',
     f.rank().over(Window().partitionBy('DateTime').orderBy('Volume')).alias('rank')
 )
 .groupby('DateTime')
 .pivot('Symbol')
 .agg(f.first('rank'))
 .orderBy('DateTime')
)
```

By calling `result.show()` you'll get:

```
+-------------------+----+----+----+
|           DateTime|   A|AAPL|MSFT|
+-------------------+----+----+----+
|2010-09-13 09:30:00|   1|   2|null|
|2010-09-13 09:31:00|   2|   1|null|
|2010-09-13 09:32:00|   2|   1|null|
|2010-09-13 09:33:00|null|   1|null|
|2010-09-13 09:34:00|   1|   2|   3|
+-------------------+----+----+----+
```

Make sure you understand the difference between `rank()`, `dense_rank()` and `row_number()` functions, as they behave differently when they encounter equal numbers in a given window - you can find the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968912/difference-in-dense-rank-and-row-number-in-spark).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try to implement your code. In your answer, did you ranked stocks by volume? How can I apply my custom function/another metric?

Comment: Yes, it was ranked by the volume. If you want to implement your function, you need a user defined function (UDF) for this. You can find an example here: https://gist.github.com/zoltanctoth/2deccd69e3d1cde1dd78. However, they might be slow in Python, so you might be interested in porting the code to Scala, in which UDF doesn't suffer from performance issues. Good luck!

Comment: I am not sure how to implement it. My rdd is a pipelineRDD, which is a collection of pandas.DataFrames. I am not sure how to transform/apply your solution to pipelineRDD

Comment: @Biarys this is a different API.

Comment: You can use rdd.toDF() method for going from rdd to DF. Check the types with df.printSchema() afterwards, as some might need casting.

Comment: hmmm, yeah... as I mentioned in the beginning, I have a bunch of stock data that I need to go thru. I get that rdd by calling ```rdd = sc.parallelize(data.keys).map(data.read_data)``` where for each key it reads data from HDF5 file. rdd.toDF gives me ```ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```. rdd looks like ```[                    ...6 columns],                     ...6 columns],                     ...6 columns]]```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214307/discussion-between-biarys-and-0xdfdfdfdf).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Biarys/6eb017ca43c6ab0116b6eddc9785cfe6  Please join chat room if you can